# Creating a dropdown of bootstrap CSS classes with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to create a drop-down of all available classes in a specific CSS file to test out the design and decide what's the best class for my element. The functionality I'm interested in is that when a class is selected from the drop-down, it will be applied to the element. The second part is easy, however, I am unable to create the list of classes using the ng-repeat directive. I want to do this on Bootstrap CSS (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Comment: show your code if you have any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: https://gist.github.com/geksilla/6543145
which is exactly what I was looking for :)